# Как сделать несколько языков на сайте ?

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

нужно на двух или больше языках (для интерфейса)

Comment: Создаешь языковые файлы типа:

ru.php 

    <?php
    $_LANG['button_name'] = "Кнопка";


en.php 

    <?php
    $_LANG['button_name'] = "Button";

Дальше в шаблоне вместо названия кнопки подставляешь переменную. Ну а какой файл (en.php или ru.php) подключать в шаблон - узнавай из userAgent'a пользователя.

Хранить в БД языковые пакеты - бред, лишние запросы.

Comment: @lampa, не понимаю как вывести ? к примеру есть форма

     <form action="" method='POST'>
     <select name="lang" id="">
        <option value="1">Russian</option>
        <option value="2">English</option>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="enter">
     </form>


    <?php 
    $lang = $_POST['lang']; 


    ?>

Comment: @Surfer Сейчас ответ расширенный напишу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем вот расширенный ответ пишу тут, т.к. в комментарии не помещается:

файл `index.php`

```
<?php
$lang = isset($_SESSION['lang']) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : 'ru';
include('languages/' . $lang . '.php');

echo "Текущий язык: " . $_LANG['language'];
```

Файл `languages/en.php`

```
<?php
$_LANG = array(
    'language' => 'en',
    'button_name' => 'Button',
    'title' => 'english site',
    ...
);
```

Файл `languages/ru.php`

```
<?php
$_LANG = array(
    'language' => 'ru',
    'button_name' => 'Кнопка',
    'title' => 'русский сайт',
    ...
);
```

Вот, самый нормальный способ - это держать настройку языка в сессии, если её нет - то запрашивать у пользователя. С сессиями, думаю, ты умеешь работать)

Comment: тут клавное следить откуда берется lang в сессии, а то file inclusion очевидный

Comment: @donkey просто для себя стоит усвоить, что сессии как БД, данные стоит фильтровать.

Answer (score -1):

весь контент хранить в бд на разных языках